How to use font icon in Nativescript TabView (Nativescript 8)
The resources I can find on the internet are all very old. Latest answers are at least 4 year old.
All I need to achieve is to use font icon in my TabView. These are what I tried and none of them work. Just need a solution to get the work. Thanks.
<TabViewItem title="&#xf015; Home" class="fas">
    <Frame id="items">
        <Items/>
    </Frame>
</TabViewItem>

<TabViewItem :title="getTitle('&#xf015; Home')" iconSource="">
   <Frame id="items">
      <Items />
   </Frame>
</TabViewItem>

<TabViewItem title="Home">
  <StackLayout>
      <Label class="fas fa-home" text=" Home" />
      <Frame id="home">
          <Home />
      </Frame>
  </StackLayout>
</TabViewItem>

